# Automatically calculate value of TextBox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to get the value of textbox3 automatically by calculating textbox1-textbox2 when textbox1 and textbox2 values entered.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>//enter value as 100
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>//enter value as 50, Once we enter 50 result should appear in textbox3

<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>//Once we enter 50 result should appear in textbox3

txtbox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtbox1.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtbox2.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: "Automatically" implies client-side. Which means JavaScript. Your C# code-behind runs at the server. Please learn this distinction now or you will be forever confused.

Comment: @Kuzgun `<asp:>` tags are certainly Web.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to use the event "TextChanged" on txtbox1 and txtbox2 to do the calculations

Comment: And he should not forget to validate the values, as well,in these events or he will be getting a bunch of exceptions ;).

Answer (score 1):

If is not necessary to call back the server side for this simple operation. you can try this :

On Text1 and Text2 place onchange Event handler client side.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1" runat="server" onchange='return calculateValueText3();'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox2" runat="server" onchange='return calculateValueText3();'></asp:TextBox>
```

Add a Javascript section

```
<script>
function calculateValueText3 ()
{
//for example
document.getElementById('<%=txtbox3.ClientID%>').value = 
document.getElementById('<%=txtbox1.ClientID%>').value - document.getElementById('<%=txtbox2.ClientID%>').value
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not add , The OP need subtraction!

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onchange='return Calculate();'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" onchange='return Calculate();'></asp:TextBox>
```

if you are using javascript------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Calculate(){

document.getElementById('<%=txt3.ClientID%>').value = 
document.getElementById('<%=txt1.ClientID%>').value - document.getElementById('<%=txt2.ClientID%>').value;
}
</script>
```

now if you are using jquery------

```
function Calculate(){
$("#<%=txt3.ClientID%>").val() = 
$("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>").val - $("#<%=txt2.ClientID%>").val();
}
```

please change the IDs with your IDs
this will work